# How to put elements from a file into a 3D List? Python

Tags: python, list, 3d

I am trying to figure out how to get elements from a file into a 3D list.

For example, if my people.txt file looked like:

```
3 4   

SallyLee
MallieKim
KateBrown
JohnDoe
TreyGreen
SarahKind
```

But I ONLY want `SallyLee` etc in the 3D list without the top numbers.

So far I have coded:

```
def main(): 
    list = []


    peopleFile = open("people.txt")
    peopleRead = peopleFile.readlines()

    for lines in peopleRead:
        list.append([lines])

    peopleFile.close()
    print(list)
main()
```

This then prints it WITH the numbers, and not in a 3D list.

An example of what I am trying to do is:

```
[[[SallyLee],[MallieKim],[KateBrown]],[[JohnDoe],[TreyGreen],[SarahKind]]]
```

where every third person is "grouped" together.

**I am not expecting anyone to code anything for me!**

I just hope that someone can lead me into the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if all you're looking for is strings (not numbers) you can start your for loop off with a condition to pass any element that has numbers. You can do this with the `try:`/`except:`.
Next you can use the parameters of the range function to make a list of the indices in which you're interested in. If you want to group by threes, you can have `range` make a list of the multiples of three (0,3,6,9,...)

Here's my code:

```
file = open('text.txt','r')

i = 0
names = []
for line in file:
    line.split() #This will split each line into a list
    try: #This will try to convert the first element of that list into an integer
        if int(line[0]):  #If it fails it will go to the next line
            continue
    except:
        if not line.strip(): #This will skip empty lines
            continue
        names.append(line.strip()) #First let's put all of the names into a list


names = [names[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(names)-1,3)]
print names
```

Output:

```
[['SallyLee', 'MallieKim', 'KateBrown'], ['JohnDoe', 'TreyGreen', 'SarahKind']]
```